# How do I get rid of this 'Install Flash' popup?

Tags: kubuntu, flash, 16.10

This pops up every reboot in the tray:

[image]

I don't plan to ever use/install Flash so how do I get this to stop pestering?

Comment: Is the package `kubuntu-restricted-addons` installed? If it is, try to remove that package.

Comment: Doesn't that come bundled with ffmpeg and other goodies?

Comment: Yes, but it also recommends `flashplugin-installer`. I suppose your choice is to either remove `kubuntu-restricted-addons` (and with that `kubuntu-restricted-extras`) and install the "goodies" separately, or just accept to install `flashplugin-installer` (and maybe disable it in the webbrowser).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Removed both but still get the popup.